# How much does a block's recorded time differ from the actual time that my node first sees it?

Tags: block, time

A block has a "time" and a "mediantime". Is it correct that the "time" is supposed to generally reflect the real time the block was mined and broadcast to the network? If so, how reliable is it? Assuming my node is well connected to other nodes, and sees all blocks within a few seconds after they are mined, how much can I expect the block's "time" to differ from the actual time that my node first sees the block?

Comment: Hi Deezy, I think that your question might be answered by either [How accurate is Bitcoin network time?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/a/20490/5406) or [How long does it take to propagate a newly created block to the entire Bitcoin network and why?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/10821/5406). Could you check out whether either answers your question? If yes, you can flag your question as a duplicate of that, otherwise, please let us know what remains unanswered of your question, so we can focus on that.

Comment: Ah thanks Murch, yup those answer it!